# Pull out data from different tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a question regarding pulling data from different tables in `MYSQL`. I'm sorry if this question has already been answered elsewhere, but I just can't seem to make sense of it.

I want to pull out the categories that are bound to the user's chosen newspapers.

I've got a table that tracks the user's chosen newspapers with **user_id** and **newspaper_id**.
A table with the **newspapers** and another table with the **categories**.
And at last a table which has both the **newspaper_id** and the **category_id**.

Is this possible to do with a single query? I'm really no good with sub select queries. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a basic `join` query.  If you are going to user SQL you should learn SQL.  There are many online resources and books that can help with this.

Comment: Agree with @GordonLinoff. If you really want someone to do this *for* you, I would suggest at least putting your schema into a http://sqlfiddle.com demo so it's easier for people to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining is probably the way to go:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM   categories c
JOIN   newspaper_categories nc ON c.category_id = nc.categroy_id
JOIN   newspaper_users nu ON nu.newspaper_id = nc.newspaper_id
WHERE  nu.user_id = <some id>
```